# Stuttering problems

Tags: medications, pain, neurology, speech, stammering-stuttering

I am a college student with stuttering problems. My first language is Spanish and my second language is English. I came to the U.S four years ago. I didn't stutter that much back then on my first days in the U.S, but as English became my first language, the problem worsened more and more. Now today, I can't even say a sentence in English without stuttering and I avoid talking to my teachers, partners,colleagues etc. I don't even go to office hours because of that fear. I use mathstack  exchange as a way out to avoid going to office hours. Any advice?. Right now, speech pathologists haven't made any significant progress in finding the cure for stuttering, so what can I do in the meantime?. I have never tried taking medications because that would be the perfect inducer for doing drugs and other things that go against my ethics, but is taking medication worthwhile?.

Answer (score 1):

As a speech-language pathologist, I will say you should still see an SLP. While there is no "cure" for stuttering, an SLP can work on specific strategies tailored to you. Go to the American Speech-Language Hearing Association's ([ASHA](http://www.asha.org/profind/)) website to find a professional near you. Many universities also have speech and hearing clinics where their graduate students work under the supervision of licensed professionals at low or no cost to people who go to the clinic.

Regarding medication: there are no medications approved to "treat stuttering." Many people who stutter also have co-existing anxiety disorders and could benefit from consultation with their physician on these matters. Beware, though, of any physician who prescribes a medication to help with stuttering.